# Different output of logging an element in Chrome an IE

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the below script in Internet Explorer, the output of `console.log(target_el)` is as expected:

```
<div class="hidden"></div>
```

However, in Chrome the output is:

```
<div class="visible"></div>
```

Even funnier, the output of `console.log(target_el, target_el.className)` in Chrome will be:

```
<div class="visible"></div> "hidden"
```

Why is that so?

```js
function change_el_class(target_el, target_class) {
  console.log(target_el)
  target_el.className = target_class
}

let el = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0]
change_el_class(el, 'visible')
```

```html
<div class="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: In my chrome (v75) the output is `<div class="hidden"></div>`...

Comment: Code snippet. The dev tools console will show you live output, not a snapshot.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: please don't use Chrome console, the snippet console works fine for me as well

Comment: Just change `let` to `var`

Comment: @Maurice how does that matter? This is an issue with whether the console is printing live objects or not.

Comment: It might be an incompatibility issue. Good ol' IE isn't doing well with javascript.

Comment: @Maurice IE doesn't even *have* `let`. There's no "compatibility issue".

Comment: @JaredSmith yes, that's why it won't change the classname. You answered yourself.

Comment: @Maurice That isn't consistent with the order of events. If it were failing on the line with `let`, the function wouldn't get called at all.

Comment: @Maurice: but isn't the output in IE something one would actually expect? The class name is logged before the actual change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) (This is for *arrays* but is applicable)

Comment: I don't think there is an issue here. IE is correct in its ouput, so is Chrome, but they are logging at different times.

Comment: Nevermind. This is too broad.

Comment: @Maurice It isn't too broad at all. You just don't seem to be understanding the question and the answer. Please see this demo in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/d2p1hbL8/ - I `console.log()` the array when it has `5` items, right? So why when I expand it in the console does the console show an array of 10 items? This is the root of OP's question. This behavior is present for all objects/arrays in JavaScript + modern browser consoles.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you @TylerRoper. After editing question it is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser logging happens *when free time is provided*. Means object may be already changed. This behavior especially can be seen in some frameworks like AngularJS.

You can try this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(target_el)))
```

or other ways to make deep copy of object.

[Read more](https://code-maven.com/logging-javascript-objects)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. However, logging the clone as per your suggestion produces an empty object in both IE and Chrome. Also, I am not sure how would logging a clone of an **already changed** object produce a result as of before the change?

Comment: @barciewicz No, when you do `JSON.stringify()` it produces immediately, only `console.log` happens later